# Android. Toolbar уезжает за пределы экрана при открытой клавиатуре

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть activity внутри блок TextEdit обернутый в NestedScrollView. Проблема состоит в том что при открытии клавиатуры для поля которое ближе к низу экрана toolbar уезжает вверх.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/contact_data_root"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="test.ru.ContactData">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include  layout="@layout/content_contact_data" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_cab_done_mtrl_alpha" />



   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: в манифесте в нужном активити попробуйте добавить `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`